# How to force download an image on click with django and aws s3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, django-storage

I have this view, which takes a user_id and image_id. When the user cliks the link, check if there is an image. If there is, then I would like the file to force download automatically.

template:

```
<a class="downloadBtn" :href="website + '/download-image/'+ user_id+'/'+ image_id +'/'">Download</a>
```

Before I was developing it in my local machine, and this code was working.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def download_image(request, user_id=None, image_id=None):
    try:
        ui = UserImage.objects.get(user=user_id, image=image_id)
        content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(ui.image.url)
        wrapper = FileWrapper(open(str(ui.image.file)))
        response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=content_type)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="image.jpeg'
        return response
    except UserImage.DoesNotExist:
        ...
```

But now I am using aws s3 for my static and media files. I am using django-storages and boto3. How can I force download the image in the browser?

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def download_image(request, user_id=None, image_id=None):
    try:
        ui = UserImage.objects.get(user=user_id, image=image_id)
        url = ui.image.url
        ...
        ... FORCE DOWNLOAD THE IMAGE
        ...
    except UserImage.DoesNotExist:
        ...
        ... ERROR, NO IMAGE AVAILABLE
        ...
```

Comment: I have done something like this use xsendfile with apache2,is this helpful?

Comment: @Ykh Thank you, but I am not so sure.

Answer (score -2):

You can just return a HttpResponse with the image itself.

```
return HttpResponse(instance.image, content_type="image/jpeg")
```

This will return the image's byte stream. The Content-type header is to show the images in platforms like Postman.

Comment: This doesn't download the image, instead it displays as a part regular html. Also its not the actual image.